Using lightning-emp-api in Console apps
We know that embedding components that continuously poll server is not good for console apps. Polling continuously means the app is constantly sending requests to the server, even when there's no new data. This consumes significant server resources, leading to slower performance for the polling app and potentially impacting the overall Salesforce org's performance.
Does this holds true for emp-api component as well? As far as I know, imp-api components are based on different architecture where long-polling mechanism is used. So, will this also impact performance? Will the emp-api component in not focused tabs will receive the events?
What is the best practice here?
